# Power supply problem, what is the correct solution?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, ripple

[image]

My result is "No" because the DC voltage is around 14.86 v and the ripple voltage is around 9.9 volts but I'm not convinced about the result especially for the ripple voltage. Does anybody get the same result?
Here are my calculations

$$V_{peak} = 15 * 1.414 - 1.4 = 19.81$$

$$V_{rip} = \frac{1}{f \times R_{load} \times C} \times V_{peak} = \frac{1}{100 \times 20 \times .001 }\times 19.81 = 9.905V$$

$$V_{dc} = 1-1/(2 \times f \times R_{load} \times C) \times V_{peak} = 14.86V $$

Comment: `because the DC voltage is around 9 v and the ripple voltage is around 6 volts.` are you sure? How? Where? Ask yourself: Does U1 (7812) have 12VDC output?

Comment: I just updated my post, had the wrong calculations submitted

Comment: Your calculations are wrong. \$R_{load}\$ in the original formula is the load of the bulk capacitor (i.e. \$V_{DC}/I_{load}\$). But in the actual circuit, the load is the linear regulator loaded with 20R. Tip: The load current flowing through input and output of the linear regulator is the same. Plus, don't forget the diode drops when calculating the peak voltage across the bulk capacitor.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i'm still quite confused about this as what you are saying is different from what my text book outlines and I can't find anythi g on the web to explain it. Do you know know of a site that explains this better?

Comment: Rohat is correct. In calculating ripple, the expression is dv/dt = i/C, and dv = i dt/C.. In this case you can replace dv and dt by delta v and delta t. Delta t is just 1/2f, so 1/100 is correct. If there were no regulator, it would be as you suggest. However, the current in the resistor is just 12/20, or 0.6. It's not 19.81/20 because the capacitor voltage is not what is being applied to the resistor. So the nominal ripple will be 6 volts, not 9.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the question is whether the supply is operating correctly or not.

**A practical answer:**
The LM7812CT requires a voltage difference of at least 2VDC across its input and output terminals. This voltage is called **Dropout Voltage**. So the minimum input voltage for proper operation should be \$\mathrm{V_O+V_{DROP}=12+2=14V}\$. Since the input voltage comes from a bridge rectifier+smoothing capacitor, the valley of the ripple should not be below 14VDC.

According to the given info in the question, the valley of the ripple is \$\mathrm{V_{in-min}=V_{DC} - (V_{rpp}/2)=17.64-4.22/2=15.53V}\$. This is higher than the required minimum input voltage. So the answer is **yes,  the supply is operating correctly**.

**A detailed answer:**
The ripple factor formula you're using is a simplified form. When it comes to practice, there are some other things to consider like the ripple current flowing through the smoothing capacitor. Anyways, let's use the simplified formula:

$$\mathrm{V_{rpp}=\frac{I_{LOAD}}{2\cdot f_L\cdot C}}
$$

If the circuit is operating correctly, the output voltage should be pure 12VDC. So the output current is \$\mathrm{I_{O}=12V/20\Omega}=0.6A\$. Since 7812 is a linear regulator, its input and output currents are equal. Thus \$\mathrm{I_{LOAD}=I_O}\$ and \$\mathrm{V_{rpp}=0.6A/(2\cdot 50Hz\cdot 1000\mu F)=6Vpp}\$. The expected ripple voltage is 6V and the measured ripple voltage is 4.22V which is lower than expected. This is good. So, the answer is **yes, the supply is operating correctly**.

Comment: Thanks Rohat, I appreciate this immensely but where did you get the "simplified formula" from because its different from mine and i have found quite a few varieties on the web

Comment: @HukaBee89 the formula is simply derived from \$\Delta q = I \cdot \Delta t\$ and \$\Delta q = C \cdot \Delta V\$. It's simplified because it is assumed that the voltage change during charging and discharging to be linear and equal *(but in fact they are exponential)*. And diode drops and ripple currents are all neglected.

Comment: Thanks Rohat that makes a lot more sense. NB the diode drops were included, I accidentally left that out but I've fixed it up now. Cheers